why does estimation of this proper integral fail?
I have the following integral $ \int_2^\infty  \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^p} dx  $ and $ \int_0^\frac{1}{2}  \frac{1}{x^(\ln x)^p} dx  $
I know that if I have something like $ \int_2^\infty  \frac{1}{x^q(\ln x)^p} dx  $  where $q\neq1$ and $ \int_0^\frac{1}{2}  \frac{1}{x^q(\ln x)^p} dx  $ where $q\neq1$ in both cases I cas use some estimates like Convergence of $ \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x^q(\ln x)^p} dx $
Why for $q=1$ I can't?  Wh the only possible way to solve the question is by calculating  by hands the integral and not using some estimates?  I  want an answer to this specific question and not to the calculus of the integral

$\ln x$ pretends to be a power function, a very very weak power function. For example,
$$
\int x^{n-1} \mathrm{d}x = \begin{cases}
  \frac1n x^n + C, & n \neq 0 \quad \text{(We are the family of power functions.)} \\
  \ln x + C, & n = 0 \quad \text{(I want to be a power function!)} 
\end{cases}.
$$

When $q \neq 1$, $\ln x$ is overwhelmed by $x^q$. It cannot affect the big picture, so we neglect it by replacing it with $1$ or $x^{\varepsilon}$.
But $q = 1$ is the edge case. Now a small change can flip the whole result, and we should consider $\ln x$ seriously.


A metaphor may be helpful.

If you put a stone on a horizontal seesaw, either the left or right end will go down. (An integral either converges or diverges.) It dependes where you put the stone ($x^q$) and how mass of the stone is distributed ($(\ln x)^p$).

If you put the stone far away from the pivot ($q \neq 1$), the position determines the outcome and the mass distribution does not matter.

However, if you put the stone (its geometric center) just above the pivot ($q=1$), the mass distribution will be the prime factor.
If you think the stone's center of mass is at its left (estimate $\ln x$ as $1$ or $x^\epsilon$), then the left end will go down; if a bit to the right (estimate $\ln x$ as $x^\epsilon$ or $1$), the right end will go down.
As you can see, those estimations are too rough to determine result. We have no choice but to inspect mass distribution in detail.


